# Error while Installing IMDbPY on MacBook

Tags: python, macos, package, imdbpy

I am trying to install IMDbPY on my MacBook running on 10.12.4 with python version 3.5.2. I did find a couple of question threads addressing the issue but the suggestions offered do not seem to help me.
Following are the outputs from my terminal.

```
host-vlth5x-205:IMDbPY-3.5 apple$ pip install IMDbPY
Collecting IMDbPY
  Using cached IMDbPY-5.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/gd/f_5prpbn13j_xy22k_4nlvgh0000gn/T/pip-build-k_hgg84y/IMDbPY/setup.py", line 200
        print 'Created locale for: %s.' % ' '.join(languages)
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/gd/f_5prpbn13j_xy22k_4nlvgh0000gn/T/pip-build-k_hgg84y/IMDbPY/
```

Post this, I have tried downloading the latest stable version of IMDbPY-3.5 [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/78/aa/16a4151a9c8f4eb2fd0800c4664f72ac6cf7383ff2c5b43a4e5debf76b2a/IMDbPY-3.5.tar.gz)  and installing the package manually via the terminal, which gave me the following error:

```
host-vlth5x-205:IMDbPY-3.5 apple$ python setup.py
  File "setup.py", line 128
    except SystemExit, e:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, IMDbPY is a Python 2.7-only library.  It can't (yet) work on Python 3.x.

To fix your problem, install Python 2.7